# Error 1004 when Filtering Top 10 in Pivot Table with VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I've set up my Pivot Table, filtered it by dates, and sorted by sales. Now, I'm trying to filter the top 10, but I keep getting **Error** **1004: Application-defined or object-defined error**.

```
'Ventas means Sales & Total Ventas means Total Sales.
 With .PivotFields("Ventas")
            .Orientation = xlDataField
            .Position = 1
            .Function = xlSum
            .NumberFormat = "#,##0"
            .Name = "Total Ventas"
        End With

ptTable.PivotFields("Total Ventas").AutoShow Type:=xlAutomatic, Range:=xlTop, Count=10, Field="Total Ventas"
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `PivotFields` as a *"row"* and `DataField` as a *"value"*.

```
ptTable.PivotFields("SKU").PivotFilters.Add2 Type:=xlTopCount, _
    DataField:=ptTable.PivotFields("Total Ventas"), Value1:=10
```